# lightdm launches upstart with a proxy configuration. Why?

Tags: lightdm, proxy

My computer seems stuck with a bad case of an hardcoded proxy. I have already tried setting no proxy in the Ubuntu configuration utility and applying the change system-wide. Grepping `/etc` for the proxy gives no results.

I tried seeing what processes do have this configuration variables:

```
pstree -p | grep -P "'"$(sudo grep -ialP '\0?https?_proxy=.*?\0?' */environ | cut -f1 -d'/' | grep -P '[0-9]+' | tr '\n' '|')"'"
```

The first process that gets highlighted is `upstart`, which is lanuched by `lightdm` (not highlighted).

Why is `lightdm` launching `upstart` with a proxy configured? How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

This was most likely caused by the contents of my `~/.profile` file, which defined the relevant environment variables.

If this shouldn't help you, then this increasingly nuclear command should?

```
sudo bash -c " grep -ial $HTTP_PROXY ~/.* ||
               grep -rial $HTTP_PROXY ~/.* ||
               grep -rial $HTTP_PROXY ~ ||
               grep -rial $HTTP_PROXY /etc ||
               grep -rial $HTTP_PROXY $(find / -maxdepth 1 | grep -vP '(/$)|(/home)|(/tmp)|(/etc)') "
```